# How to display in template count of rating for every Picture?

Tags: django

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class PictureRate(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    picture = models.ForeignKey(Picture)
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2,decimal_places=1)
```

views:

```
def index(request):
    pictures = Picture.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('index.html',{'pictures':pictures}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

in template:

```
{% for p in pictures %}
    {{ p.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

How to display in template count of rating (`rate`) for every `Picture`?

Comment: `{{ p.picturerate_set.rate }}` should do the trick

Comment: @limelights Sorry. I mean how many `PictureRate` has every `Picture`

Comment: `{{ p.picturerate_set.count }}` then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an objects foreign key relationship you do like this, go via its `_set`.

```
{{ p.picturerate_set.rate }} #to access it's field.
{{ p.picturerate_set.count }} #to count the number of rates your picture has.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use annotation:

```
from django.db.models import Count
pictures = Picture.objects.all().annotate(rating_count=Count('picturerate'))
```

and in the template:

```
{{ p.rating_count }}
```